# MySQL - Trouble with creating user defined function (UDF)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, user-defined-functions, dbvisualizer

I'm trying to create this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION remove_non_alphanum (prm_strInput varchar(3000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(3000)
DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN

  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE v_char VARCHAR(1);
  DECLARE v_parseStr VARCHAR(3000) DEFAULT '';

  WHILE (i <= LENGTH(prm_strInput) )  DO
    SET v_char = SUBSTR(prm_strInput,i,1);

    IF v_char REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9]$' THEN
      SET v_parseStr = CONCAT(v_parseStr,v_char);  
    END IF;

    SET i = i + 1;
  END WHILE;

  RETURN trim(v_parseStr);
END
```

But MySQL says:

> 13:52:45  [CREATE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 1064, SQL State: 42000]  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

What could I being wrong?  The syntax looks correct to me.

Comment: Comment out things (starting with the IF in the WHILE loop in this case) one at a time & test to better determine the issue.

Comment: Actually am I supposed to be running this in the query window?  This page seems to imply I need to compile a UDF first http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-functions.html

Comment: @Greg, that would be the case if you were writing a function in C language. Your code is SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://www.dbvis.com/forum/thread.jspa?threadID=2217&tstart=5&messageID=12690).

I turns out it was some weird DB Visualizer issue.

Enclosing the complete block in "--/" and "/" worked for me:

```
--/
CREATE FUNCTION remove_non_alphanum (prm_strInput varchar(3000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(3000)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE v_char VARCHAR(1);
  DECLARE v_parseStr VARCHAR(3000) DEFAULT '';
WHILE (i <= LENGTH(prm_strInput) )  DO
  SET v_char = SUBSTR(prm_strInput,i,1);
  IF v_char REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9]$' THEN
        SET v_parseStr = CONCAT(v_parseStr,v_char);  
  END IF;
  SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
RETURN trim(v_parseStr);
END
/
```

Answer (score 9):

You have to change the delimiter so you can use `;` inside the function:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION remove_non_alphanum (prm_strInput varchar(3000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(3000)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE v_char VARCHAR(1);
  DECLARE v_parseStr VARCHAR(3000) DEFAULT '';
WHILE (i <= LENGTH(prm_strInput) )  DO
  SET v_char = SUBSTR(prm_strInput,i,1);
  IF v_char REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9]$' THEN
        SET v_parseStr = CONCAT(v_parseStr,v_char);  
  END IF;
  SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
RETURN trim(v_parseStr);
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

In [MySQL Command-Line Client](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html) (and many other SQL clients) the default delimiter is `;`. So, when you type your original code, MySQL thinks the first command ends where the first `;` is found (at line 5, as the error message states), thus you get an error because this is not valid SQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION remove_non_alphanum (prm_strInput varchar(3000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(3000)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
```

If you change the delimiter to anything else, MySQL identifies the complete command (from `CREATE FUNCTION` to `END` and runs it. Voilá! Your function is created. Finally, when you run your function, the code runs just fine because the function body is composed of several statements using the default delimiter.

Comment: I don't understand why this would be required

Comment: Hmm now I get this error:  14:20:15  [DELIMITER - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 1064, SQL State: 42000]  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$

Comment: @Greg: all I can say is that it works for me as I wrote it (MySQL 5.0). What are you using to run the code? The manual states that DELIMITER is a command of the mysql command line client. I'm using HeidiSQL and works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  That makes perfect sense now.  I wonder if it's not running because of a db visualizer issue?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to

```
--/
CREATE FUNCTION ... 
/
```

is:

```
@delimiter $$;
CREATE FUNCTION ...
@delimiter ;$$
```

More info: http://www.dbvis.com/doc/main/doc/ug/sqlCommander/sqlCommander.html#mozTocId437790