# Converting MSSQL function to MySQL function

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mysql-workbench

I am trying to convert this user defined function (taken from a MSSQL) and tweak it so that I can run it MYSQL. I have made several attempts but all seem to error on the declare variable.

I am running the following version: 5.6.11-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

```
USE [DataGB]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[FullPostCodeFix]    Script Date: 11/20/2013      16:10:44 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO


CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FullPostCodeFix] (@Postcode  VARCHAR(20))  
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)

BEGIN 
/*
Puts postcode into correct format if it is currently in any of the below formats
AB12AA
AB 12AA
AB1 2AA
AB 1 2AA
Returns @Postcode
*/

DECL ARE @District Varchar(50)
DECLARE @Remainder Varchar(50)
DECLARE @Sector Varchar(50)

SET @District=  CASE 
            WHEN LEN(@Postcode) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@Postcode)) =     len(@Postcode) THEN SUBSTRING(@Postcode,1,(len(@Postcode) - 3))
            WHEN LEN(@Postcode) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@Postcode)) < 3 THEN     SUBSTRING(@Postcode,1,(len(@Postcode) - 3))
            ELSE SUBSTRING(@Postcode, 0, LEN(@Postcode) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@Postcode)) + 1)
        END


SET @District = dbo.PostcodeFix(@District)

SET @Remainder= RIGHT(@Postcode,3)

SET @Sector = @District +  ' ' + LEFT(@Remainder,1)

SET @Postcode = @District +  ' ' + @Remainder

RETURN @Postcode

END
```

My attempt at creating a MYSQL version is below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FullPostCodeFix (Postcode  VARCHAR(20))  
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)

BEGIN 


DECLARE District Varchar(50)
DECLARE Remainder Varchar(50)
DECLARE Sector Varchar(50)

SET District=  CASE 
            WHEN LEN(Postcode) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Postcode)) =     len(Postcode) THEN SUBSTRING(Postcode,1,(len(Postcode) - 3))
            WHEN LEN(Postcode) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Postcode)) < 3 THEN     SUBSTRING(Postcode,1,(len(Postcode) - 3))
            ELSE SUBSTRING(Postcode, 0, LEN(Postcode) - CHARINDEX(' ',     REVERSE(Postcode)) + 1)
        END

SET District = dbo.PostcodeFix(District)

SET Remainder= RIGHT(Postcode,3)

SET Sector = District +  ' ' + LEFT(Remainder,1)

SET Postcode = District +  ' ' + Remainder

RETURN Postcode

END
```

The error that I get is as follows:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE Remainder Varchar(50) DECLARE Sector Varchar(50)
```

There is another function called from within the function "FullPostCodeFix". This is my attempt:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION PostCodeFix (strDistrict  VARCHAR(20))  
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
    DECLARE intASCII INTEGER;
        SET strDistrict = LTRIM(strDistrict);
        SET strDistrict = RTRIM(strDistrict);

            IF LENGTH(strDistrict) > 4  OR LENGTH(strDistrict) = 0 THEN RETURN 'ERROR: ' + strDistrict; 
            ELSE 
                BEGIN
                    SET intASCII = ASCII(LEFT(strDistrict, 1));
                    IF  ( intASCII > 47 AND intASCII < 58 ) THEN RETURN 'ERROR: ' + strDistrict;
                    ELSE
                        BEGIN
                            SET intASCII = ASCII(SUBSTRING(strDistrict, 2, 1));
                            IF  ( intASCII > 47 AND intASCII < 58 ) THEN SET strDistrict = LEFT(strDistrict, 1) + ' ' + RIGHT(strDistrict, LENGTH(strDistrict)-1);
                                SET intASCII = ASCII(SUBSTRING(strDistrict, 3, 1));
                            IF  ( intASCII < 48 OR intASCII > 57 ) AND (intASCII <> 32) THEN RETURN 'ERROR: ' + strDistrict; 
                            ELSE IF LENGTH(strDistrict) < 4 THEN     SET strDistrict = LEFT(strDistrict, 2) + ' ' + RIGHT(strDistrict, LENGTH(strDistrict)-2); 
                            END IF;
                        END IF;
                RETURN strDistrict;
            END IF;
```

Comment: `DECL ARE`? Is that a copy/paste error or is that really in your function?

Comment: What errors are you getting or which functions you can't convert?

Comment: Sorry, that is a copy and paste error.

Comment: Is that it? Or are you having other errors?

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Can you update code for the second function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok lets start, replace MS-SQL functions with MySQL equivalent functions.

```
 MSSQL         MySQL
 LEN()         LENGTH()
 SUBTRING()    SUBSTR()
 CHARINDEX()   INSTR()
```

below is documentation and list of all MySQL String functions 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Here is correct MySQL Syntax that I have verified.

```
CREATE FUNCTION FullPostCodeFix (Postcode  VARCHAR(20)) RETURNS VARCHAR(20) 
BEGIN   
    DECLARE district VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE remainder VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE sector VARCHAR(50);
        IF LENGTH(Postcode) - INSTR(' ', REVERSE(Postcode)) = LENGTH(Postcode) THEN SET district = SUBSTR(Postcode,1,(LENGTH(Postcode) - 3));
        ELSEIF LENGTH(Postcode) - INSTR(' ', REVERSE(Postcode)) < 3 THEN SET district = SUBSTR(Postcode,1,(LENGTH(Postcode) - 3));
        ELSE SET district = SUBSTR(Postcode, 0, LENGTH(Postcode) - INSTR(' ',     REVERSE(Postcode)) + 1);
        END IF;  
    SET District = dbo.PostcodeFix(District);
    SET Remainder= RIGHT(Postcode,3);
    SET Sector = CONCAT(District,' ',LEFT(Remainder,1));
    SET Postcode = CONCAT(District,' ',Remainder);  
    RETURN Postcode;
END
```

Here is your second function

```
CREATE FUNCTION PostCodeFix (strDistrict  VARCHAR(20))  
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
    DECLARE intASCII INTEGER;
        SET strDistrict = LTRIM(strDistrict);
        SET strDistrict = RTRIM(strDistrict);

            IF LENGTH(strDistrict) > 4  OR LENGTH(strDistrict) = 0 THEN RETURN 'ERROR: ' + strDistrict; 
            ELSE                 
                    SET intASCII = ASCII(LEFT(strDistrict, 1));
                    IF  ( intASCII > 47 AND intASCII < 58 ) THEN RETURN 'ERROR: ' + strDistrict;
                    ELSE                        
                        SET intASCII = ASCII(SUBSTRING(strDistrict, 2, 1));
                        IF  ( intASCII > 47 AND intASCII < 58 ) THEN SET strDistrict = LEFT(strDistrict, 1) + ' ' + RIGHT(strDistrict, LENGTH(strDistrict)-1);
                        END IF;
                        SET intASCII = ASCII(SUBSTRING(strDistrict, 3, 1));
                        IF  ( intASCII < 48 OR intASCII > 57 ) AND (intASCII <> 32) THEN RETURN 'ERROR: ' + strDistrict; 
                        ELSEIF LENGTH(strDistrict) < 4 THEN     SET strDistrict = LEFT(strDistrict, 2) + ' ' + RIGHT(strDistrict, LENGTH(strDistrict)-2); 
                        END IF;                        
                    END IF;
                RETURN strDistrict;                
            END IF;
END
```

Comment: Thank you, I have replaced the function with the MYSQL equivalent...however I still get the same error. Have I declared the variables correctly?

Comment: Place your MySQL Code in your question

Comment: have a look a this screenshot, it may help you understand my error: http://www.greenhill-group.co.uk/images/capture.png

Comment: It still has the same issue, http://www.greenhill-group.co.uk/images/capture2.png

Comment: I have updated the answer, this should work. To make sure that it does work you might need to change `DELIMITER` refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628390/mysql-trouble-with-creating-user-defined-function-udf

Comment: :] it has worked although I have noticed the function is calling another function. I have added my attempt at the second function.. I think I am missing something.

Comment: You forgot several `END IF` statements and used `ELSE IF` instead of `ELSEIF`